# faking hostname in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to test response time of webpages hosted on many backends. These hosts are behind load balancer and above that I have my domain.com.

I want to use python+selenium on these backends but with spoofed hostname, without messing with /etc/hosts or running fake DNS servers. Is that possible with pure selenium drivers?

To illustrate problem better, here is what's [possible in curl](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1613-make-an-http-request-to-a-machine-but-fake-the-hostname) and I'd like to do the same with python+selenium:

Comment: Why do you need to spoof the hostname?

Comment: because application I'm testing is forcing redirection to domain.com if it was not properly accessed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a UNIX system, you can try something as explained here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/can-i-create-a-user-specific-hosts-file-to-complement-etc-hosts

Basically you still use a `hosts` file, but it's only for you, located in `~/.hosts`, setting the `HOSTALIASES`environment variable.

Comment: not a best solution I'm affraid and it is still falling into"(...)without messing with /etc/hosts or running fake DNS servers".

Comment: This is not messing with `/etc/hosts`. This is adding something to the profile of the user which runs the test, while `/etc/hosts` is a system file. Also, since it's in an environment variable, it will only be valid for the session of the shell running the test, so even the user environment will not be messed up.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

Selenium drives browsers using the WebDriver standard, which is by definition limited to interactions with page content. Even though you can provide Selenium with configuration options for the browser, no browser provides control over `Host` headers or DNS resolution outside of a proxy.

But even if you could initiate a request for a particular IP address with a custom `Host` header, subsequent requests triggered by the content (redirection; downloading of page assets; AJAX calls; etc) would still be outside of your control and are prohibited from customizing the `Host` header, leading the browser to fall back to standard DNS resolution.

Your only options are modifying the local DNS resolution (via `/etc/hosts`) or providing an alternative (via a proxy).